# require('child_process').exec stops the program

Tags: node.js

In Windows 10, 
I have a express server which launch a command in a route

```
const exec = util.promisify(require('child_process').exec);
module.exports = router.use(function(req, res) {
  exec('start "Title" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe')
  .then((r) => {
    res.send("Ok.");
  })
  .catch((e) => {
    res.status(401).send("Running error.", error);
  });
}
```

When a client make a request to this route, the Plex Server starts but the server never renders "Ok.". But, If I manually close the Plex Server, then program flow reaches res.send("Ok.");

I'm not able to launch this command without stopping server response until Plex Server is closed.

***Desesperate edit***

There's something I'm missing.
If I run node and in the node commad line I write:

```
console.log(require('child_process').exec('start "xx" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe"')); console.log("ok");
```

It opens Plex Serven, prints "ok" and node console waits for another command

However, if I create a mynode.js like this

```
console.log(require('child_process').exec('start "pp" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe"')); console.log('ok');
```

From windows CMD:

```
c:\tmp> node mynode.js
```

It opens Plex Server, prints "ok" but until I don't close Plex Server, it doesn't continue.

Comment: Try not double quoting the path. Also check for errors.

Comment: The command works ok. The problem is that it doesn't print "ok" until the process it's finished

Comment: If you do `.spawn(<your process>)`, you could check for the stdout or stderr. May be the Plex Server is not sending any event back of start that is expected for process to continue and exit from there?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of annoying trial and error I have found a solution to this problem.

```
exec('start "Title" "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe', { timeout : 1000 })
```

After one second, exec returns control to the main program.

Comment: This is my only working solution. I think there is a problem in quotes, order of parameters, I don't know...

Answer (score 0):

### Run your command in the background

Here's what is actually happening: `exec` waits for your command to return with a success or fail. However, when your command runs, it starts a TTY in the sub process, meaning your `exec` statement will never return anything (until the process either fails or you manually exit it).

What you want to do is launch the Plex server in the background and then continue execution. 
The timeout is a nasty hack and could potentially be dangerous: imagine for whatever reason after waiting a second your plex server has not started, you would continue execution, and return a false positive.

Just replace your command with:

```
exec('start /b "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe')
```

If that isn't working for you can you also try these:

Redirect output to file:

```
exec('start /b "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe > output.txt')
```

Redirect output to null device:

```
exec('start /b "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Plex\\Plex Media Server\\Plex Media Server.exe > NUL')
```

Comment: Yes, timeout is a nasty solution but start /B doesn't work for me. I have tried in another computer, with another Plex Server an the execution continues (even without /B). I thinks threre's a problem in my server computer because I don't understand what the problem is

Comment: I see you put `/B`, i have noted `/b`, any difference? How about redirecting the output to a file or NUL? see edit

Comment: In Windows, there is no difference between /B and /b. NULL output doesn't work either